# What's the pun in "Clowns divorce. Custardy battle.”?

Tags: meaning, jokes, pun

What is the pun in this joke?

> Clowns divorce. Custardy battle

by Simon Munnery

Comment: I believe the full quote is "Clowns divorce. Custardy battle ENSUES." The better pun would have been: "Clowns divorce, on adultery grounds. Finally realized it was a three-ring circus."

Comment: Clown sacked, sues for funfair dismissal.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When a couple divorce, there is often an argument over which parent gets to have their children live with them. Having responsibility for the children in this situation is called custody and hence the debate is known as a custody battle.

However, clowns (comedy circus performers) often have mock fights, in which a food substance known as custard is thrown around, often in the form of pies. Such a fight might be known as a custard-pie fight. However, a fight can be called a battle so it could also be referred to as a custard battle. You might describe the battle as 'custardy' i.e. involving custard.

So when clowns fight, you could describe it as a 'custardy battle', which is a pun on 'custody battle', which you might get when clowns divorce. 'Custardy' and 'custody' will generally sound the same when spoken.

Comment: Er ... it's *custody* when it involves who shall be guardian (L *custos*) of the children.

Comment: Thanks Stoney - I though it looked wrong when I wrote it. Someone's since edited my answer to correct.

Answer (score 15):

The joke is about the word: /'kʌstədi/ (British RP transcription).

When you hear the joke, this word might mean *to do with custard*, in other words the adjective *custardy*. We can make adjectives like this by adding *-y* to a noun. So for example, take the compound noun *Stack Exchange*, we can make the adjective *Stack Exchangey* by adding this suffix:

- Don't you give me any of your Stack Exchangey nonsense!

Here the speaker is making a new adjective *custardy* from the noun *custard*. Custard is a dessert sauce that clowns use in their show. They throw custard pies at each other, for example.

[image]

However, /'kʌstədi/ might also mean *custody*. This is a word we use a lot in divorces. It is about who becomes the legal guardian of the children. We use the term quite loosely, though. For example, we might talk about who's going to get custody of the goldfish!

**Ref**: photo from: US Daily review. [URL](http://usdailyreview.com/dress-appropriately-for-the-circus-event/)

Comment: Note that for people who don't totally ignore the letter R, the pun is somewhat forced. We know what was meant, but it's kind of like when you have to explain a joke: it's no longer funny.

Comment: @Martha Agreed. I'm sure it's a British English joke - that's why I gave that transcription. Otherwise it'll be /ˈkʌs·tərdi/ versus /ˈkʌs·tə·di/ :(

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, it's British. Specifically, it was told at the Edinburgh Festival and [nominated for an award](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-edinburgh-east-fife-34039927).

Comment: @DavidRicherby If it's BE, I reckon it deserves it! I've used it about ten times already!

Comment: I think a better example for the -y suffix would be "Wibbly wobbly timey wimey" given its origin, but I'm horribly bias.

Comment: @Pharap *biased.

Comment: @Martha what Rs would you pronounce to make the word sound different?

Comment: @WendyG: uh, the ones that are present? As in, the "r" in *custard* is not there for decorative purposes?

Comment: @Martha when you know a word so well you don't see it as individual letters but as a single item (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/develop/word-recognition) I honestly didn't see the 'r' in "custad" which is odd as being from the UK south I put the R in all sort of odd words "bath" for instance